# ASP.Net MVC 3 : Production environnement

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, configuration, prerequisites

I've developed a small site with ASP.NET MVC3, I will have to deploy in the next few days, and I would like to know which prerequisite the server should have(like this I can contact their IT service to be sure they have everything).

They already have IIS 7.5, the last .net framework installed, but should they have something installed/configured for ASP.NET MVC 3? I searched, but I found only non relevant links :(

Comment: [Install it via Web Platform Installer or download the installer directly to run it yourself.](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/13/aspnetmvc3-released.aspx) First hit for "asp mvc 3 deploy". ;)

Comment: The server doesn't need anything specific for MVC projects. Just the .NET framework you are using and a web site which is using an application pool with the same .NET framework configured. On the first install you need to use a setup to get the dlls registered correctly but after that you can just publish over the previous files.

Comment: @Mika - what do you mean dlls registered correctly? Generally there is no technical reason to need to use a setup program to deploy an ASP.NET website.

Comment: Yeah, generally there isn't but I haven't been able to install a single MVC3 project without running the setup at first install though I haven't tried that hard since a setup does the trick. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, ASP.NET should be installed and configured on IIS.

There're the two general methods that ASP.NET MVC application can be deployed with:

1. Bin Deploy - it means that you will include the asp.net mvc dlls with the published web site. This time nothing else is required, just the published web site files. Read more about it on [Phil Haack's blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx)
2. PreInstall ASP.NET MVC on server - using [Microsoft Web Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=MVC3) or [the standalone downloader](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=1491). Both links taken from [ASP.NET MVC3 Home](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3). This will install all the required dlls on server, so they will not be required to be passed along the published web site.

That's just it, nothing more. ASP.NET MVC is known to have some problems when deployed to iis 6, but for the version you are deploying to, problems are solved. Read about those problems [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/)

Comment: Have you a link to do the PreInstall?

Answer (score 3):

You can bin deploy an MVC3 app so that it doesn't require anything other than IIS with ASP.NET and .NET 4 installed.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx